# do until loop - only gets one of the values?

Tags: asp-classic

I have a list with 17 rows with form values, where you can select multiple items with a checkbox and write in a text field on every row next to the checkbox, and I'm trying to insert the two values into the db but I only get what I have selected in the checkbox, not what I have written in the text field?

My formpage looks like this:

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM menu;"
set rs = conn.Execute(sql)

i = 0
do until rs.eof %>
    <input type="text" name="newheadline" value="">                    
    <input type="checkbox" name="menu_id<%=i%>" value="<% = rs("menu_id") %>">   
    <%  i = i + 1
    rs.movenext
loop %>
```

And on page2 I try to loop trough it and here I only get the value of the checkbox, not the value of the `newheadline`?

```
i = 0   
do until i = 17
    response.write (request.form("menu_id"&i))
    response.write (request.form("newheadline"&i)) 
    i = i + 1       
loop
```

What am I missing?  Thanks!

Comment: what's your language and database engine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You write out your textbox like:

`<input type="text" name="newheadline" value="">`

But you try to read it like:

`response.write (request.form("newheadline"&i))`

You'll need to append the value of `i` onto each name attribute, exactly like you do with your checkbox:

```
<input type="text" name="newheadline<%=i%>" value="">
```